# Transfering ERC20 Token on behalf of another wallet with only signed messaged

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain, erc-20, ethers.js

Is it possible to transfer ERC20 tokens on behalf of another wallet, with only the signed message or signature of the of the wallet you are transferring tokens from?.

Answer (score 0):

To do that you would need to implement something like [EIP-2771](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2771) and in your ERC-20 contract decode the msg.sender in the transfer method.

Hope it helps